# Aliasing a table in a window function?

Tags: sql, data-science, data-analysis, presto

I am trying to alias a table in a window function, but not sure what I am doing wrong as when I alias it gives error that the columns cannot be resolved

```
    SELECT e.city,
       e.time,
       e.day,
       e.id,
       m.id
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY e.id,
                                    e.bin
                       ORDER BY e.time ASC) rnk
   FROM table e
   JOIN table2 m 
   on m.id = e.id
   WHERE e.status = 'YES'
   AND e.day BETWEEN date '2019-05-06' and date '2019-05-08')
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: you have to alias the sub-query too, as `e` here.

Comment: but isnt all the column names in the sub query aliased with e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the `e` alias in the outermost `select`.  However, there is nothing in scope with that alias.  The inner `from` doesn't "reach out" like that (scopes do "reach in" the other way though).

So:

```
SELECT e.city, e.time, e.day, e.id
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             rank() OVER (PARTITION BY e.id, e.bin ORDER BY e.time ASC) as rnk
      FROM table e
      WHERE e.status = 'YES' AND
            e.day BETWEEN date '2019-05-06' and date '2019-05-08'
     ) e
-------^ here
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks ! quick question if I had a table that I wanted to join, and alias that as well, do I just add that alias next to the e where you showed outside the subquery towards the end? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @chris90 . . . You would do `) e JOIN <other table> ot ON . . . `.